# How to persist signed_request with PHP SDK when user is not logged in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have an app tab which does not require the user to authorize the app. When the tab first loads, I have access to the signed request like so: `$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();`

The app then makes various AJAX calls to the server. With each AJAX call, signed_request is not persisted. I would like the signed_request to be available during these AJAX calls so I can do `$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();` again.

I have read that when a user is logged in, the JS SDK and PHP SDK share the signed_request via a cookie. Is there a cookie I can set during the initial page load that will persist signed_request during AJAX calls, so it is accessible through the PHP SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With each AJAX call, signed_request is not persisted. I would like the signed_request to be available during these AJAX calls so I can do $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest(); again.

Why don’t you just add it as a parameter to your AJAX calls …?

You know the parameter name, you know the value – so just put it in there with the other data you’re sending.

Comment: The way I'm currently doing it is already better than what you're suggesting. Here's how I'm doing it, first: `$_SESSION['signedRequest'] = $facebook->getSignedRequest();` and later: `$signed_request = $_SESSION['signedRequest'];`. However, it requires that I verify the signed_request myself. I would like to have the PHP SDK verify the signed_request for me.

Comment: I can’t guess what you’re doing if you neglect to describe it in detail :-) – The SDK tries to read the signed request from $_REQUEST['signed_request'] first – so feel free to put it in _there_, instead of just into $signed_request.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was just trying to answer your question "Why don't you just add it as a parameter...".  POSTing the signed request is a good idea, but I'd like to know if there's a more elegant way.

Comment: Like I said, you can fill $_REQUEST['signed_request'] from your session – then the PHP SDK should “find” it. If that’s more “elegant” – is for you to decide …

Comment: Sorry, bad choice of words. I should have said, as from the question: 'Is there a cookie I can set during the initial page load that will persist signed_request during AJAX calls, so it is accessible through the PHP SDK?'

Comment: If you already have that value in your session, what’s wrong with populating $_REQUEST yourself? Anyway, if you look into the `getSignedRequest` method, it tries to fetch the signed request from `$_COOKIE[$this->getSignedRequestCookieName()]` on the second try. And the method `getSignedRequestCookieName` just returns the string `fbsr_1234567890`, with 1234567890 being the app id …

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this, but it did not work... `setrawcookie('fbsr_'.$app_id, $_REQUEST['signed_request'], time()+36000);`

Comment: upvoted because this is the solution i ended up using, but it did not answer the question.